# AppInitialize not firing in WCF Service Application on WIndows Server 2012

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-8, windows-server-2012

We have some WCF Service Applications which are deployed to Windows Server 2012.

In these services, there is a class called Initializer in the /app_code/ folder. This class is as follows;

```
    public class Initializer
{
    public static MicroserviceInitilization.MSInit iInit = null;

    public static void log_string(string line)
    {

        //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(app_path))
        //{
        //  return;
        //}

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
        String log_path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
        File.AppendAllText(log_path + "log.txt", sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {

        log_string("AppInitialize called");
        // This will get called on startup
        MicroserviceInitilization.MSInit iInit = new MicroserviceInitilization.MSInit(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log_directory"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["service_endpoint_name"]);
    }
}
```

When this application is run in my local dev environment ( IIS7 on Windows7 ), this initialization code is executed as expected and a log file is generated. When I deployed this WCF service to a Windows 2008R2 server with IIS7.5, the initialization code fired as expected.

When this same application is deployed to our Windows 2012 production environment, ***the services work as expected, but none of the initialization code is fired***; there are no log files & the other init code in MSInit shows no record of having executed.

We tried working with the "Application Initialization" features of IIS8 on this server, but nothing obvious seemed to work.

In an attempt to try other things, I changed the initialization code to use a ServiceHostFactory pattern like so;

```
    public class CBHMicroservice : ServiceHostFactory
{

    public static void log_string(string line)
    {

        //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(app_path))
        //{
        //  return;
        //}

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
        String log_path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
        File.AppendAllText(log_path + "log.txt", sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }

    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        log_string("CreateServiceHost called");
        log_string(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log_directory"]);
        log_string(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["service_endpoint_name"]);
        MicroserviceInitilization.MSInit iInit = new MicroserviceInitilization.MSInit(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log_directory"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["service_endpoint_name"]);
        iInit.log_string("CreateServiceHost called");
        // return new ServiceHost(typeof(Initializer), baseAddresses);
        return new ServiceHost(typeof(CBH.IDProofing.KBAUsersService.KBAUsers), baseAddresses);
    }
}
```

and my .svc file looks like this;

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CBH.IDProofing.KBAUsersService.KBAUsers" CodeBehind="KBAUsers.svc.cs" Factory="CBH.IDProofing.KBAUsersService.App_Code.CBHMicroservice" %>
```

Again: locally, this code is firing as expected and the desired log files are being created and the entries in the log file are correct.

The log_string function shown in the above code would drop a log file in the same path as the .svc file. This same log_string function exists in the MicroserviceInitilization DLL, but it logs to a defined folder.

At this point, we are at a loss as to why these services work on all other versions of Windows except 2012.

Comment: Dump the IIS Metabase in both machines and do a comparison.